# Copy 3 tables from access to an existing excel template

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I´m trying to make a macros that run several queries in Access and then it copies the 3 resulting tables to an Excel template.
The problem is I don't know how to copy each table to the clipboard so I can make it paste them to the Excel file 
So long, I have the following code:

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim DPath As String

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    DPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path

    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlApp.EnableEvents = False

    xlApp.Workbooks.Open DPath & "\Templates\Modelo de Supervivencia" & ".xltm", True, False
    Debug.Print xlApp.Version
    Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this function will help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset

Comment: Or this http://accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Export.htm

Comment: have you tried using the wizard under External Data-Excel ?  if you are automating the process of exporting the tables.  save the query that results from the export and then use the export query as a guide to finishing the VBA.